# how to get sum of selected radio button in javascript from different table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

There are two tables: table#1 and table#2. In table#1, there are four columns.  Each column has some radio buttons. User can select only one radio button from each column. I want to set the following condition in my code:

1. User must select radio button from both table.
2. If the total selection of radio button is 5, user must select 3 radio button from table#1, and 2 from table#2. If the total selection of radio button is 4, user must select 2 radio button from table#1, and 2 from table#2. If the total selection of radio button is 3, user can select 2 radio button from table#1, and 1 from table#2 or user can select 1 radio button from table#1, and 2 from table#2.

   3. User can not select more than 3 radio button from table#1. [Table#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruEca.jpg)
      [Table#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iwks.jpg)

I have done condition#1 and condition#3. How can I set condition 2 in javascript by using table id?

Here is my code for condition#1 and #condition#3:

1. Condition#1

   ```
   //tableId sat
   $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
       var $checked = $('#sat').find(":radio:checked");
           if (!$checked.length) {
               alert('You are violating Rule 6. You can not take 3 courses in a day but it is possible if you take 5 courses in a semester..');
               event.stopImmediatePropagation();
               return false;
           }
   });

   //tableId fri
   $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
       var $checked = $('#fri').find(":radio:checked");
           if (!$checked.length) {
               alert('You are violating Rule 6. You can not take 3 courses in a day but it is possible if you take 5 courses in a semester..');
               event.stopImmediatePropagation();
               return false;
           }
   });
   ```
2. Condition#3

   ```
   // tableID fri
   $("#fri input[type='radio']").change(function(){
       var count = $("#fri input[type='radio']:checked").length;
       if(count>3){
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
         alert("You cannot add more than 3");
       }
   });

   //table sat
   $("#sat input[type='radio']").change(function(){
       var count = $("#sat input[type='radio']:checked").length;
       if(count>3){
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
         alert("You cannot add more than 3");
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: You just have to set the statement for 2nd table (`#sat`) in your "Condition#3" to `count>2`  because you can't select more than two radiobutton in that table, as you stated. In this case user can select 1-3 rb in the first, and 1-2 in the second table

Comment: oh in fact!  as user not suppose to select only just 2 options, you can add an extra statement to the 2nd table's submit event, which is checking that the count of selected options in total is at least 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function to check for the criteria in condition 2

```
function validateRadionCount() {
  var radioCountInSat = $('#sat').find(':radio:checked').length;
  var radionCountInFri = $('#fri').find(':radio:checked').length;
  var totalCount = radioCountInSat + radionCountInFri;

  switch(totalCount) {
    case 5:
      if (!(radioCountInSat === 3 && radionCountInFri === 2))
        return false;
      break;
    case 4:
      if (!(radioCountInSat === 2 && radionCountInFri === 2))
        return false;
      break;
    case 3:
      if (!(radioCountInSat === 2 && radionCountInFri === 1) || !(radioCountInSat === 1 && radionCountInFri === 2))
        return false;
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }

}
```